# Python replace text value regular expression

Tags: python, python-re

Is it possible to just replace a specific text's value in a file python? The below code replaces the string however I could'nt find a way to replace only the project_id or project_name's value.

```
import re 

def replace():
    with open("/Users/test/file.txt", "r") as sources:
        lines = sources.readlines()
    with open("/Users/test/file.txt", "w") as sources:
        for line in lines:
            sources.write(re.sub(r"Settings", 'Project_settings', line))

    
replace()
```

file.txt

```
Settings
######################
project_id = "468324678997"
project_name = "test"
```

output:

```
Project_settings
######################
project_id = "468324678997"
project_name = "test"
```

I would like to replace project_name's value to "abc"

Desired output:
file.txt

```
Settings
######################
project_id = "468324678997"
project_name = "abc"
```

Comment: Can you add your desired output? Do you want to replace the word "test" in your example file?

Comment: What happened when you tried running the code, and how is that different from your desired result?

Comment: In your own words, where you have `re.sub(r'^# project_name', 'abc', line)`, what *exactly* do you think that means? What source are you using to learn how to use regular expressions, and what happened when you tried following a tutorial?

Comment: Updated the question, i'm using  re.sub to  replace the string and it works. however i'm having issues to replace only the variable value using regex.

Comment: Perhaps that's because there is no Python variable named "project_name."  That's a piece of text that you are writing to a file, not the name of a variable in a Python script.

Comment: Why does your expected output have `Settings` and your code has `Project_settings`?

Comment: Also, what do you expect to happen if you had a line like `project_name = "Settings Test"`?

Comment: Settings is not going to occur anywhere in the file. 
Why does your expected output have Settings and your code has Project_settings - its just an example code for replacing a specific string in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a dictionary of config overrides, not regex

This way, you are not accidentally replacing all matching text

```
def replace(file, overrides):
    with open(file, "r") as sources:
        lines = sources.readlines()
    with open(file, "w") as sources:
        # skip the header rows
        next(lines)
        next(lines)
        for line in lines:
            config_key = line.split(' = ')[0]
            if config_key in overrides:
                sources.write('{} = {}\n'.format(config_key, overrides[config_key]))

overrides = {
  'project_name': 'abc'
}
replace("/Users/test/file.txt", overrides)
```

There are likely better Python libraries that can read property files and allow you to override specific values

Comment: IMO, that isnt really needed because if the headers are removed you can just `import config.py`

Comment: So, we agree in that point: once recognized the _major pattern_ of given file-format (and ignoring headers) you can just use existing libs to parse & modify.

Answer (score 1):

#### Automate the text-editor's regex-replace

My recipe for replacing each matching line in an **arbitrary formatted** text-file.

As arguments to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub)
you could use a pair of regular-expressions: **pattern-to-match** and **replacement**, like regex-tuple `(r'^Settings', r'Project_settings')`.

The data structure to store these could be a list of tuples (pairs), like `replacements`.

```py
import re

replacements = [
    ('^Settings', 'Project_settings'),
    (r'^project_name = "(.*)"', r'project_name = "abc"'), # simply replaces with fixed value
    (r'^project_id = "(.*)"', r'project_id = "P-\1"')  # copies in the found group 1 at \1
]


def replace():
    lines = []
    with open("project_properties.cfg", "r") as config:
        for line in config.readlines():
            for pair in replacements:  # apply each replacement that matches line
                line = re.sub(pair[0], pair[1], line)  # substitute found pattern with replacement
            lines.append(line)  # add each read line to the buffer (if changed or not)

    with open("project_properties_.cfg", "w") as config: # Note: used a new filename
        config.writelines(lines)


replace()
```

Will result in desired output (plus inserting-replacement at `project_id`):

```
Project_settings
######################
project_id = "P-468324678997"
project_name = "abc"
```

#### Parsing and Updating with existing libs

As [*OneCricketeer*'s answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68676242/5730279):

When you manage to ignore the header, you will recognize **strong similarity (i.e. `key = value` representation)** to at least two common config-file formats:

- [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file)
- [.properties file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties)

This would allow you to research and find existing libraries, like Python's built-in [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html):

- to [modify an INI-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637467/modify-ini-file-with-python)
- or [properties-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819696/parsing-properties-file-in-python/2819788#2819788)